# How to use boolean with constructor in java?

Tags: java, constructor, boolean

We have an activity that will store and display the information of an employee.
I've already created no-modifier class named Person and a public class named Employee which is the the main method. My problem is I don't know how to make the boolean in the class Person which will be used in the main method with a scanner.

```
 class Person {

 private String name;
 private int contactNum;
 private boolean status;
 public boolean isRegular;

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public int getContactNum(){
    return contactNum;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public void setContactNum(int contactNum){
     this.contactNum=contactNum;

//how to make the boolean of status and isRegular?
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Person P = new Person();

    System.out.println("Type employee's name, contact number");
    System.out.println("Press Enter after every input");
    P.setName(input.nextLine());
    P.setContactNum(input.nextInt());
    
    System.out.println("Press Y if employee is regular or N if not");
    //how to use boolean here that comes from the class Person?

    System.out.println("Name: "+ P.getName());
    System.out.println("Contact Number: "+ P.getContactNum());
    System.out.println("Status:" + this is where the user is ask to Press Y if employee is regular or N if not )//the status is if the employee is regular or not.
```

Comment: Create a constructor that takes those parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for your code:

```java
System.out.println("Press Y if employee is regular or any other key if not");
P.setRegular(input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Your constructor

```java
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int contactNum;
    private boolean status;
    private boolean isRegular;

    //No arg constructor
    public Person() {
    }

    //Full arg constructor
    public Person(String name, int contactNum, boolean status, boolean isRegular) {
        this.name = name;
        this.contactNum = contactNum;
        this.status = status;
        this.isRegular = isRegular;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getContactNum() {
        return contactNum;
    }

    public void setContactNum(int contactNum) {
        this.contactNum = contactNum;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public boolean isRegular() {
        return isRegular;
    }

    public void setRegular(boolean regular) {
        isRegular = regular;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I've noticed an error in the above code and fixed it. This line should be:

```java
P.setRegular(input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

You can print booleans as is just like any other Java primitive. `

```java
System.out.println("Status:" + P.isRegular());
```

would print `Status: true` or `Status: false`.

If you want it to print `Status: Yes` or `Status: No`, you could do something like this:

```java
System.out.println("Status: ".concat((P.isRegular())?("Yes"):("No")));
```

Comment: @ Cenfracee Thanks, and what about here>System.out.println("Status:" + what should I put here?) to print the regular or not regular status. Like this- Status: Regular